# Python - Please suggest a faster alternative to this code using isin

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, isin

I have written a program to find comets in astronomical images however it runs slow on one area. I have already optimised it for speed by using numpy and cupy where possible.

I can trace the speed problem down to one operation:

```
t1=np.isin(thirdsplit,file3new)
```

`thirdsplit` and `file3new` are both numpy arrays with float values in them. They can range in size but typically both might be 600 x 600 in size.

The above line compares each position in the two arrays and looks to see if the corresponding position in the other array is identical. If so `True` is returned at that position in the resulting t1 array of equal shape.

eg

```
thirdsplit[100,100] = 2.80000
file3new[100,100] = 2.8000
```

therefore
`t1[100,100]` will return `True`

is there a way to rewrite the line

```
t1=np.isin(thirdsplit,file3new)
```

so that it runs much faster?

For the record I searched for alternative answers. I found one similar question but that uses Pandas but Pandas is not being used in my program.

Comment: Look at `isin` code.  It uses `in1d`, that in turn uses `unique` on the 2 arrays, and `argsort` on their concatenation.

Comment: careful with `float` equality tests.  Have you tried `np.isclose`?

Comment: Apologies I just realised there is one small twist to this saga. 
thirdsplit is a numpy array with floats in it and typically might be 500 x 500 in size. 
file3new is list of floats (eg [100.298, 230.21,512.645...]
The aim is to produce an array of True and False values (same shape as thirdsplit) which is the result of testing each element in thirdsplit to see if it is in file3new.
Sorry about the error.

Answer (score 0):

`isclose` with broadcasting should work, and be more accurate with floats:

```
In [112]: x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3); y = np.array([1.,5.])
In [113]: np.isclose(x[:,:,None],y)
Out[113]: 
array([[[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]]])
In [114]: _.any(axis=-1)
Out[114]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

compared to:

```
In [115]: np.isin(x,y)
Out[115]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

### edit

An example where `isclose` gets things right - due to how it handles floats

```
In [117]: x = np.arange(.1,1,.1).reshape(3,3); y = np.array([.3,.7])
In [118]: x
Out[118]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
       [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]])
In [119]: x.tolist()
Out[119]: 
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004],
 [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
 [0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9]]
```

compare:

```
In [121]: np.isin(x,y)
Out[121]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
In [122]: np.isclose(x[:,:,None],y).any(axis=-1)
Out[122]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

`isin` uses `==` test, and can fail due to floats precision.

Comment: Ok speed test time

I have amended the code as follows.

[code]
import numpy as np
import math
import time


start = time.time()

    
x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
y = np.array([1.,5.])

for i in range(0,10000):
    
    answer = np.isin(x,y)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)



start = time.time()

for i in range(0,10000):
    
    npsrch = np.isclose(x[:,:,None],y)
    
    answer=npsrch.any(axis=-1)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
[/code]
Result was:

0.22699594497680664
0.6640110015869141

Using np.isclose appears to be much slower.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting of the code above